# escape less / greater than javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

I'm having a problem trying to escape some code... Basically, I want to escape "<" and ">" but I want them to APPEAR in my #output div as "<" and ">". Currently, they appear as as "&lt;" and "&gt;" on the page.

This is obviously to prevent anyone exploiting / injecting scripts on the page. This is my code:

```
var textval = $("#textarea").val();                   //textarea

filtered = textval.replace(/</gi,"&lt;");           //replace "<"

$("#output").html(filtered);                     //insert textarea data into div
```

Can anybody spot what I am doing wrong, or are there any better ways of doing this?

Many thanks

EDIT: I do want SOME html tags (like <b> to work, so I can't use $.text(); unfortunately..)

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
var textval = $("#textarea").val();
$("#output").text(textval);
```

jQuery offers two methods - $.text() and $.html() where the method names speak for themselves :)

Comment: The jQuery developers had us in mind; No need to do all that nasty HTML sanitation ourselves. :-)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned, I want SOME html, like bold tags to actually work...

Answer (score 0):

A little different replace, but works for me (even with `.html()`).

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/LmLrq/)**

```
var str = $('#textarea').val();
$('#result').html(str.replace(/<|>/ig,function(m){
    return '&'+(m=='>'?'g':'l')+'t;';
}));

<textarea id="textarea">
    Hello, <b>World</b>!
</textarea>
<div id="result"></div>
```

*(This is just to verify it can be done, `.text()` is the better approach)*

Comment: +1 for showing it can be done (and helping me with a somewhat related issue )