# regex replace characters within tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm already using a html parser, but I need to create a regex that will select the < and > symbols within the first instance of `<code>` tags - in this case, the one with the class "html".

```
    <code class="html">
        <b>test</b><script>lol</script>
            <code>test</code> <b> test </b>
        <lol>
                        </lol>

            <test>
    </code>
```

So every < or > within the indented area starting from `<b>` to the start of the last `</code>` should be replaced, leaving the outer `<code>` tags alone.

I'm using javascript's .replace method and would like all < and > symbols within the code area to turn into ascii &#60; and &#62;.

I imagine its best to use a look forward/back regex using $1 etc. but can't figure out where to begin, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Couldn't you just get the `<code>` content using the HTML parser you're already using, and do a regular replace? This does not sound like solid regex territory.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225096/escape-less-greater-than-javascript

Comment: why dont try using `.text('new text')` of jquery`s

Comment: Trying to parse HTML with regex will [drive you insane](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2430028).

Comment: @user2000008 - That post is unhelpful. As the OP stated very clearly in the post, he's not trying to parse (which has already been done) - he's only trying to escape the `<` and `>` characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this? In this example I'm creating a variable and populating the variable with html, just to get things started

```
var doc = document.createElement( 'div' );
doc.innerHTML =  ---your input html here
```

Here I'm pulling the code tag

```
var string = doc.getElementsByTagName( 'code' ).innerHTML;
```

Once you have the string then simply replace the desired brackets with

```
var string = string .replace(/[<]/, "&#60;)
var string = string .replace(/[>]/, "&#62;)
```

then just reinsert the replaced value back into your source html

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
var elem = $('.html');
elem.text(elem.html());
```

This will not necessarily use literally `&#60;` for escaping; if you're fine with a different escape, it's much simpler than anything else you can do, though.

If you have multiple elements like that, you might need to wrap the second line in an `elem.each()`; otherwise the `html()` method will probably just concatenate the content from all elements or something similarly pointless.